# Using variables to create N triples in python

Tags: python, variables, rdf, turtle-rdf

I am currently trying to use variables to create a graph of N triples, I am not having any trouble assigning the variables, but i keep getting an error message. Here is the code:

```
from rdflib import Namespace, URIRef, Graph
from StringIO import StringIO


xmlns = "http://www.example.org/lexicon#"
rdf = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
lemon = "http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#"
graph = Graph()
F = open("new_2.txt", "r")
for line in F:
```

This is the part where I assign the variables. This is pretty long and I know it works so I wont include this. This following code is still part of the `for line in F:`

```
line1 = ''+synset_offset+'\rdf.lex_filenum\ '+lex_filenum+''
    line2 = ''+synset_offset+'\lemon.ss_type\ '+ss_type+''
    line3 = ''
    for item in word: 
        line3 +=''+synset_offset+'\lemon.lexical_entry\ '+iw.next()+'/n'
    line4 = ''+synset_offset+'\lemon.gloss\ '+gloss+''
    line5 = ''
    line6 = ''
    line7 = ''
    for item in S:
        pointer = ip.next()
        pos = iss.next()
        source_target = ist.next()
        line5 += ''+synset_offset+'\lemon.has_ptr\ '+pointer+'/n'
        line6 += ''+pointer+'\lemon.pos\ '+pos+'/n'
        line7 += ''+pointer+'\lemon.source_target\ '+source_target+'/n'

    contents = '''\
    '''+line1+'''
    '''+line2+'''
    '''+line3+'''
    '''+line4+'''
    '''+line5+'''
    '''+line6+'''
    '''+line7+''''''  
    tabfile = StringIO(contents)
    for line in tabfile:
        triple = line.split()                # triple is now a list of 3 strings
        triple = (URIRef(t) for t in triple) # we have to wrap them in URIRef
        graph.add(triple)

print graph.serialize(format='nt')
```

This is the other code i have that prints everything correctly, showing that it is not the variables that are not working.

```
print('''<http://example.org/#'''+synset_offset+'''> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#lex_filenum> "'''+lex_filenum+'''".
<http://example.org/#'''+synset_offset+'''> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#ss_type> "'''+ss_type+'''".
<http://example.org/#'''+synset_offset+'''> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss> "'''+gloss+'''".''')
    for item in word:
        print('''<http://example.org/#'''+synset_offset+'''> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#lex_entry> "'''+iw.next()+'''".''')

    for item in S:
        pointer = ip.next()
        pos = iss.next()
        source_target = ist.next()
        print('''<http://example.org/#'''+synset_offset+'''> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#has_ptr> "'''+pointer+'''".
<http://example.org/#'''+pointer+'''> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos> "'''+pos+'''".
<http://example.org/#'''+pointer+'''> <http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target> "'''+source_target+'''".''')
    print('''\n''')
```

Any better ideas than the way I have it done here would be very welcome

EDIT: Now i am getting this error:

```
graph.add(triple)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib-4.1_dev-py2.7.egg/rdflib/graph.py", line 352, in add
    def add(self, (s, p, o)):
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Comment: try `iw.next()` instead of `iw.next` ;-)

Comment: sweet, but now im getting this:@ `graph.add(triple)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib-4.1_dev-py2.7.egg/rdflib/graph.py", line 352, in add
    def add(self, (s, p, o)):
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
`

Comment: Are you sure that `triple` is a tuple with 3 values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to concatenate a "method" with a `str`, which means `iw.next` is the "pointer" to the method and `iw.next()` would be its return value, which is what you want.

Being explicit:

```
line3 +=''+synset_offset+'\lemon.lexical_entry\ '+iw.next()+'/n'
```

Update (regarding the next error):

`triple` has to be a `tuple` with 3 elements, just like the function signature says:

```
add(self, (s, p, o))
```

Ignore `self`, since you're calling the instance method.

I'm pretty sure that `triple` has another type, so check that out (the easiest way is `print triple` in the `for` statement).